# What is the best secure, simple and common way to save checkBoxes status?

Tags: c#, checkbox, save

I have a lot of checkBoxes on the form. User can check some of them and then close the application. If he opens the application again, checkBoxes should be checked. I mean application can save checkBoxes status. I want to save checkBoxes status in a file that nobody can read or edit it. And I need a simple way too. Would you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would want to have a state class that describes your model. You can represent checkboxes as bool properties, depending on how many you have and if different users can have different variety of checkboxes, you can also store them as some sort of collection, for example `Dictionary<string, bool>` - dictionary of name-value pairs.

Now when you need to save this, you would want to encrypt it. There must be some entropy coming from the user, otherwise there is no way to protect your data from administrator access. So you can request a user to type in a password which you can use as additional entropy in your encryption method. There is a variety encryption algorithms you can use, as a starting point you can have a look at [AES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged.aspx)

To save a state class you would want to *serrialize* it. When you need to read classes back from a file, you want to *dessirealize* it. There is quite a choice of serrialization techniques, for example XML, binary, JSON.

Comment: Thank you. If a user open this file and manipulates it so there could be a mistake and there is a problem while decoding to check checkBoxes. That is why user doesn't have to access to the file. How can I make an uneditable file?

Comment: By using Access Control List and managing permissions on the folder. If the files are encrypted, a user won't be able to locate any meaningful data there, and any change in the encrypted file would most likely render it completely unusable.